# How to define a class or method after @Getmapping in a Spring Controller

Tags: spring-boot

when defining a class after @Getmapping annotation in Spring Controller, are there other ways besides Iterable see code sample below on how to define a class or method after @Getmapping in a Spring Controller,

```
@RestController
    @RequestMapping("/rooms")
    public class RoomController {
        @Autowired
        private RoomRepository roomRepository;

        @GetMapping
        public Iterable<Room> getRooms(){
            return this.roomRepository.findAll();
        }
    }
```

Are there other ways to define a class or method after  @Getmapping in a Spring Controller

Answer (score 0):

Based on [HTTP GET](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-9.3) specification:

> The GET method means retrieve whatever information (in the form of an
> entity) is identified by the Request-URI. If the Request-URI refers
> to a data-producing process, it is the produced data which shall be
> returned as the entity in the response and not the source text of the
> process, unless that text happens to be the output of the process.

So, for `GetMapping` you can return any type which defines as an `entity` (i.e. any Class which suits your requirement).